# Get all the users except current logged in user in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing:

```
    User::all();
```

to get all the users from users table. I want to select all the users except current logged in user. How should I do that? something like,

```
    User::where('id','!=',$currentUser->id)->get();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can get the current user's id with `auth()->id()`. Then pass that to the query:

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did have the id of current logged in user though, as I am writing a function in "User" model. I just did not try before asking the question, as I thought maybe != won't work. Thanks again.

Comment: How to handle the errors? like token invalid, id not found, etc.. thanks

Answer (score 79):

Using `except()` will accomplish the same thing a little more fluently:

```
$users = User::all()->except(Auth::id());
```

...or, since you already have the User id:

```
$users = User::all()->except($currentUser->id);
```

Comment: Awesome!  Works with an array of ID's as well `User::all()->except([1,2,3,4]);`  Cheers :)  This should be updated to be the best answer under the current API.

Comment: To be clear: this also fetches the current user from the DB, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Using 'except' actually retrieves ALL users.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the Auth helper, use this.

```
User::where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
App\Models\User::whereKeyNot(auth()->id)->get()
```

Using 'except' actually retrieves ALL users, then performs an extra operation on the collection to remove the current user, which is not as effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Auth;
Use App\User;

public function index()
$id = Auth::id();
$result = User::where('id', '!=', $id)->get();
dd($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The better answer is to use `whereNotIn` so that the undesired records are not retrieved at all.

The accepted answer retrieves everything & then filters it.

```php
$user_ids_to_exclude = $users_collection->pluck('id')->toArray();

$this->filtered_posts = Post::latest('published_at')
    ->whereNotIn('author_id', $user_ids_to_exclude) # This part
    ->get();
```