# How to query all except one in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4, laravel-blade

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function index() {
    $users = User::all(); // Is there a way to chain it with the except method or sth like that
    return View::make('distributors.index')->with('users',$users);
}
```

**GOAL**

I want to query all of my users table, but one.

I want to list all the user(s) for my client, but I want to hide my self.

**Question**

How do I do that ? 
Am I approaching it in the right way ?

Feel free to give me any suggestions for improvement.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with laravel, but could you use something like     `User::Where('id', '!=', '1')->get();` The 1 would be your user id

Comment: Exactly what @VincentMatte is the correct answer.

Comment: @VincentMatte : You're right !!

Comment: here you can find better solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/32627797/7373178

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean except currently logged in user, then do:

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
```

Comment: Not exactly, but very close.